# Running Wildfly in Azure App Service, how to configure JGroups for session replication

Tags: java, azure, wildfly, azure-web-app-service, jgroups

Running Wildfly as Azure App Service was possible via a custom java app [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/]. However, app service nodes don't know the internal IP address while registering with JGroups. They always expose 127.0.0.1. In order to make JGroups cluster members communicate, we need a well known IP address of the node.

How can Wildfly determine the internal IP address of the host that it can use to register with JGroups cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Per my experience, I think you can try to use Azure SDK for Java to get the internal IP address of the host from the `WebSiteManagementClient`.

Here is a sample code below for getting the internal IP address.

```
String userName = "<user-name>";
String password = "<password>";
String resourceGroupName = "<resource-group-name>";
String name = "<webapp-name>";

ServiceClientCredentials credentials = new BasicAuthenticationCredentials(userName, password);
WebSiteManagementClient webSiteManagementClient = new WebSiteManagementClientImpl(credentials);
HostingEnvironmentsOperations hostingEnvironmentsOperations = webSiteManagementClient.getHostingEnvironmentsOperations();
ServiceResponse<AddressResponse> serviceResponse = hostingEnvironmentsOperations.getHostingEnvironmentVips(resourceGroupName, name);

AddressResponse addressResponse = (AddressResponse) serviceResponse.getBody();
String internalIp = addressResponse.getInternalIpAddress();
```

To run the above sample, you need to add the dependent libraries into your Maven project, please see the dependencies below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-svc-mgmt-websites</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

More details for the key classes in the above sample code, please see below.

1. [WebSiteManagementClient](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/website/WebSiteManagementClient.html) & [WebSiteManagementClientImpl](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/website/WebSiteManagementClientImpl.html)
2. [HostingEnvironmentsOperations](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/website/HostingEnvironmentsOperations.html)
3. [AddressResponse](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/website/models/AddressResponse.html)

Comment: Thanks @Peter. While this could be a work around but it requires modifying JGroups to detect IP address. We can modify JGroups code but what about opening up firewall to allow ingress on JGroups port 7600? Is this possible in Azure App Service? Also looks like for Azure V2 the SDK is changed - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a special keyword for the `bind_addr`, see [1] for details. E.g. `bind_addr=match-address:192.168.1.*` to try to pick an IP address on a given subnet.

[1] http://www.jgroups.org/manual/index.html#Transport

Comment: Thanks @Beta. How do we know the Azure App Services subnet CIDR block? It may be running app service on 172.x.x.x or some other block.

Comment: You need to know the range of addresses assigned to you. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Azure, but most clouds assign just one address to you, so not setting bind_addr, or setting it to non_loopback may also help.

Comment: Yeah I wish that was the case with Azure App Service. It is a server-less deployment where user does not get to choose runtime environment so Azure uses a shared environment. It tells me that my site has 4 outgoing addresses and Azure can pick any of them for any of my node.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Peter's code (above) to detect the available IP addresses, then set `bind_addr` in JGroups, e.g. like this:

```
InetAddress bind_addr; // detect address by using Azure's SDK
JChannel ch=new JChannel("config.xml");
TP transport=ch.getProtocolStack().getTransport();
transport.setBindAddress(bind_addr);
ch.connect("mycluster");
```

The important thing is that you need to set the bind address before connecting the channel.